# Global shared variable clear if client connection lost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page that creates a incremented item code from the database on page load and saves that code in a public shared variable array so that when another client page is opened they do not use the same code until it is saved in the database.

```
Public Shared gCode() As String
```

When the client saves the data captured I remove the item code from the variable.

I want to know what would happen if the client lost connection to the server, how would I remove the code from the variable. I tried using the onunload event but it doesn't seem to fire.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Any suggestions appreciated

Thanks in advance

**Further explanation**

I have a Item code that we created that has specific ranges and uses for eg. GPA0741MAN1 . GP is the manufacturer, A is the category, 0741 is the item number, MAN means it is manufacturing and 1 is the manufacturing number.

I create this code using a function in vb. the page is CreateItem.aspx. When the user clicks on create new item code the code is created and saved in the variable but not in the DB as there are other information to be capured.

If another user click on the create new item before the first one saves the wont have the same code.

The problem comes in that we do not always have a stable connection to the server and the connection can drop. this causes the server to keep the variable and never lose it

Comment: Can the code be empty until the user press save? If not, you could have in the database a table for reserved code with the userid and date attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter that the client loses connection as the code on the server will continue anyway. The client will never see the output though but in this case it doesn't make a difference.

---

A different (maybe better as more standard) way would be to use `SyncLock` to create a critical section in your code.

```
Private Shared someLock as Object = New Object() ' define the lock variable on the class
```

In your method:

```
SyncLock someLock ' critical section
    ...
End SyncLock
```

The object used in `SyncLock` should be static (so that all instances of this class on different threads shared it) and private (so that it couldn't be changed outside of the class).

Comment: In my case it does matter that the client loses connection. If the client losses connection I want to take the item code out of the variable so that the next client can use it.

Comment: Well, you can't detect a client disconnection in all cases... Maybe you will need to have some kind of timeout.

Comment: I don't fully understand the SyncLock but from what I have read it won't really solve my problem as I don not increment the item code from the variable but instead I increment it from the database. I only use the variable as a check before the user saves the data that I don't create duplicate codes if another user opens a page.

Comment: So what should happen to other users if the first is in?

Comment: On page load I will select the last item code in the database e.g. "ABC123". Then I would increment it to "ABD123" and see if it exists in the global variable array. If it does I increment it again and store it in the variable. If the next user opens the page before the first user saves the item code in the DB it would not use "ABD123" but incement it

Comment: In this case, you should rather look at some solution on the database level rather than trying to do that in the code, I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41854/discussion-between-jan-gous-and-szymon)